# OpenVPN bridging with venet interfaces

Tags: openvpn, bridge, tap

I have a VPS which uses venet interfaces for its (virtual) ethernet connections.  I've managed to get an OpenVPN daemon running with tunneling, but not able to do so with bridging (tap).

Is it possible to use bridging with a virtual server using venet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled "venet" and the second result on the list goes to a [page](http://wiki.openvz.org/Virtual_network_device) that says very clearly:

```
No bridge support

Venet network device cannot be bridged together and/or with other devices.
[edit]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I want to point that some vps's allow `tun` (tunnel I presume) interface, there's tutorials on how to install openvpn using that `tun` interface

Comment: tun is for routing (i.e tunneling/layer3), tap (bridging/layer2) is for bridging. I assume most VPS' have tun support but tap is tricky for security reasons I assume; makes it easy/easier to sniff packets since you're on the same network interface.